# How to customize ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE?

Tags: android, android-photos

Is it possible to use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and customize some parts of the code? If yes, how?

I would like to add some `Toast` in the code. I know that there is the method `onActivityResult` to add some actions at the moment of the end of the activity.

But I would like to add some actions (ig. `Toast`) in other moments: for example when the user taps the screen to take the picture but before saving the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own camera app, where you provide an activity that implements `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Then, you can do whatever you want within that activity.

If, instead, you are asking how you can modify the code of hundreds of other camera apps that supply the world's `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` implementations, that is not possible.

Also, note that there is no requirement that the user tap the screen to take a picture using a camera app. They might set up a timer in the app, with the picture being taken after the timer elapses. Or, they might press a hardware CAMERA button, or press something on a Bluetooth remote, etc.